# Build 'azure-arm' errored: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, packer

I am getting the following error when I build the image for Ubuntu in Azure using packer.

1. To work with Azure I have logged in using az login.
2. I have already created the Azure service principal and created the storage as well. The storage account and resource group lies on the same location.

Getting the error when running the below command

```
$ ./packer build ubuntu.json

azure-arm output will be in this color.

==> azure-arm: Running builder ...
    azure-arm: Creating Azure Resource Manager (ARM) client ...
Build 'azure-arm' errored: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/palm-tf-dev1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccount04/listKeys?api-version=2016-12-01: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> azure-arm: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/palm-tf-dev1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccount04/listKeys?api-version=2016-12-01: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you give `Owner` role on your subscription level?